# Can't login to Oracle SQL Command Line

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I tried to find answer to this question but I didn't find any.

I just installed Oracle 11g XE2 on Windows 8.1 PC.

then, I could login to Application express at http://127.0.0.1:8080/apex/apex_admin with username: ADMIN and password given at time of installation.

But when I try to use same username/password to login to SQL command line through start menu (from same local computer) it gives me

```
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

**Failed attempts**

So, I created a new workspace. while creating workspace it let me create new schema and administrator user for schema.

Then, I again tried to login to SQL command line using following command and **new user** credentials but still can't login.

```
CONNECT username/password
```

I tried to create new user form Application express home->workspace Task->create user with Account privileges as

```
Workspace                   INTERNAL
Default Schema              APEX_040000
User is an administrator:   No
User is a developer:        Yes 
Application Builder Access  Yes
SQL Workshop Access         Yes
Team Development Access     Yes 
Account Availability        Unlocked
```

but I still can't login to sql command line with **new user** and same command

```
CONNECT username/password
```

this is the first time I am trying to install a database. Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, what password did you use as the default for SYS and SYSTEM when you installed XE?

Comment: It asked me just once to put password and that was for "ADMIN" which I used to to login to web interface "Application express"

Comment: Maybe see this thread - https://community.oracle.com/thread/718808

Comment: Application Express workspace user accounts are not the same as Oracle user accounts.  The ADMIN account you created is only for logging into Apex, not for connecting to the database directly.

Comment: @Dave - Can you tell me how to create database user?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - I tried that method. Now it gives me Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.

Comment: if you login as sys, you need to add "as sysdba"

Comment: @Raj-887 Connect with SYS AS SYSDBA, then read this: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503